# extract uncommon elements from list based on attribute in another list

Tags: java, java-stream

My Structure

```
   A {
       String id;
       String bid;
   }

   B {
       String id;
   }
```

Given

```
List<A> aList = Arrays.asList(
   new A (1,2),
   new A (2,5),
   new A (3,9),
   new A (4,10),
   new A (5, 20),
   new A (6, 8),
   new A (7, 90)
   new A (8, 1)
);

List<B> bList = Arrays.asList(
   new B (2),
   new B (9),
   new B (10)
);
```

Now i want the elements of A which don't match with any B's element should be collected in another collection and these elements should be deleted from A collection itself.

Result

```
 List<A> aList = Arrays.asList(
       new A (1,2),
       new A (3,9),
       new A (4,10)
    );

    List<A> aListBin = Arrays.asList(
       new A (2,5),
       new A (5, 20),
       new A (6, 8),
       new A (7, 90)
       new A (8, 1)
    );
```

MY take

I can think of iterating A using iterator and for each element in A iterate through B and if found keep else keep adding to separate list and delete using iterator remove.

Is there a better way to do this using stream magic? Thanks

Comment: No. Streams don't alter the original collection. What you should avoid is O(m * n) complexity. Store your the IDs of the Bs  in a HashSet. Lookups in a HashSet are O(1). So you end up with O(m) instead of an O(m * n)

Answer (score 1):

[Collectors#partitionBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-) is your friend.

First, we'll extract the `id`s from the list of `B`s into a bare `Set<Integer>`, so we can use that for lookup:

```
Set<Integer> bSet = bList.stream()
    .map(b -> b.id)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

As mentioned by JB Nizet, a `HashSet` is fit for the job.

Then it's just as simple as this – we'll partition by a given predicate. The predicate is whether `A.bid` is contained in any `B.id` (which we stored into `bSet` for convenience).

```
Map<Boolean, List<A>> map = aList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(a -> bSet.contains(a.bid)));
```

Now `map.get(true)` contains all items contained in `B`, `map.get(false)` all others.

In order to replace `aList`, simply reassign `aList`:

```
aList = map.get(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove elements from a list created with Arrays.asList(). It returns a view of the array you pass as argument, so calling remove will throw UnsupportedOperationException.

Assuming you have ArrayList instead, I still don't think you can achieve this on a single step, and certainly not with "stream magic", since streams won't allow you to modify the original collection.

In two steps, something like:

```
List<A> newList = aList.stream()
    .filter(a -> !bList.contains(a.bid))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
aList.removeAll(newList);
```

If performance is an issue, use Set or Map(with id as key) instead of List in order to perform the contains() and the removeAll() in O(1) and O(n) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Java 8 Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Here's the full example from your input:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        class A {
            public int id;
            public int bid;
            public A(int id, int bid) { this.id = id; this.bid = bid; }
            public String toString() { return "(" + id + "," + bid + ")"; }
        };

        class B {
            public int id;
            public B(int id) { this.id = id; }
            public String toString() { return "" + id; }
        };

        List<A> aList = Arrays.asList(
                new A (1,2),  // not removed
                new A (2,5),  // removed
                new A (3,9),  // not removed
                new A (4,10), // not removed
                new A (5, 20),// not removed
                new A (6, 8), // not removed
                new A (7, 90),// not removed
                new A (8, 1)// not removed
        );


        List<B> bList = Arrays.asList(
                new B (2),
                new B (9),
                new B (10)
        );


        List<A> aListBin = new ArrayList<>();
        aList.stream()
            .forEach( a -> {
                if (bList.stream().noneMatch(b -> b.id == a.bid )) {
                    aListBin.add(a);        
                }
            });

        aList = aList.stream()
        .filter( a -> bList.stream().anyMatch(b -> b.id == a.bid))
        .collect(toList());

        System.out.println("Alist-> " + aList);
        System.out.println("Blist-> " + bList);
        System.out.println("Removed-> " + aListBin);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Alist-> [(1,2), (3,9), (4,10)]
Blist-> [2, 9, 10]
Removed-> [(2,5), (5,20), (6,8), (7,90), (8,1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collectors.partitioningBy`. Is it better? Depends on your definition of better. It is much more concise code, however it is not as efficient as the simple iterator loop you described.

I cannot think of a more efficient way than the iterator route, except maybe using a string hashset for lookup of the B class id.

However, if you prefer concise code, here is the code using partitioningBy:

```java
class A {
    int id;
    int bid;

    public A(int id, int bid){
        this.id = id;
        this.bid = bid;
    }

    public boolean containsBId(List<B> bList) {
        return bList.stream().anyMatch(b -> bid == b.id);
    }
}

class B {
    int id;

    public B(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<A> aList = Arrays.asList(
        new A (1,2),
        new A (2,5),
        new A (3,9),
        new A (4,10),
        new A (5, 20),
        new A (6, 8),
        new A (7, 90),
        new A (8, 1)
    );
    List<B> bList = Arrays.asList(
        new B (2),
        new B (9),
        new B (10)
    );
    Map<Boolean, List<A>> split = aList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(a -> a.containsBId(bList)));

    aList = split.get(true);
    List<A> aListBin = split.get(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with two different classes you can't compare them directly.  So you need to reduce to the least common denominator which is the integer ID's.

```java
   // start a stream of aList.
   List<A> aListBin = aList.stream()

   // Convert the bList to a collection of
   // of ID's so you can filter.       
   .filter(a -> !bList.stream()

         // get the b ID
         .map(b->b.id)

         // put it in a list         
        .collect(Collectors.toList())

         // test to see if that list of b's ID's
         // contains a's bID   
         .contains(a.bid))

    //if id doesn't contain it, then at to the list.
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

To finish up, remove the newly created list from the aList.

        aList.removeAll(aListBin);
```

They are displayed as follows:

```java
        System.out.println("aListBin = " + aListBin);
        System.out.println("aList = " + aList);
        aListBin = [[2, 5], [5, 20], [6, 8], [7, 90], [8, 1]]
        aList = [[1, 2], [3, 9], [4, 10]]
```

Note:

- To reverse the contents of each final list, remove the bang(!) from
  the filter.
- I added toString methods in the classes to allow printing.